# Delphi: WM_COPYDATA work once

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe

Based on [this post](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/wm_copydata.htm) I have wrote a simple project to communicate two app, but it work only once and imperfect too.

If I send "stackoverflow" I'll receive "stackov" on the other side and once. It seems that the `WMGetData` procedure is not triggered anymore.

Sender code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CDS: TCopyDataStruct;
  receiverHandle : THandle;
  res : integer;
  S: string;
begin
  S:= Edit1.Text;
  CDS.dwData:= 0;   //Identify message
  CDS.cbData:= Length(S);
  CDS.lpData:= PChar(S);

  receiverHandle := FindWindow(PChar('TForm2'),PChar('Form2')) ;
  if receiverHandle <> 0 then
    res := SendMessage(receiverHandle, WM_COPYDATA, Integer(Handle), Integer(@CDS))
  else
    Caption:= 'Not Found';

  Caption:= IntToStr(Res);
  CloseHandle(receiverHandle);
end;
```

Receiver code:

```
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure WMGetData(var Msg : TWMCopyData) ; message WM_COPYDATA;

...

procedure TForm2.WMGetData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  S: string;
begin
  S:= PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
  Caption := Caption + S;
  msg.Result := 2006;   //ACK for sender app.
end;
```

Comment: Why are you casting to `Integer`? 32 bit truncation errors are ahead when you switch to 64 bit. Those args are `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`. Don't call `CloseHandle` on a window handle ever. `CloseHandle` is for kernel32 handles and not user32 window handles. You don't need to do anything to tidy up a window handle you don't own.

Comment: @David thanks for your tips. I don't know why it's casted. That's a famous one. About `CloseHandle` I see another [demo](http://delphidabbler.com/tips/51) which close handle in a try/finally manner.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of that comment. I don't think your approach is very good here.

Comment: To elaborate, you've accepted an answer here that is both incorrect and incomplete. And you've pointed at an unattributable ancient article on the Web that contains errors. Don't believe everything you read on the Web. Check and verify.

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649010(v=vs.85).aspx) specify

```
CDS.cbData:= Length(S);
```

should be

```
CDS.cbData:= Length(S) * SizeOf(S[1])
```

since the cbData member should contains the number of bytes you transfer, and delphi XE `string` type refers to a unicode string (2 bytes per characters)

Your second problem

```
receiverHandle := FindWindow(PChar('TForm2'),PChar('Form2')) ;
```

My best guess is that this call fails the second time because you changed the caption of your second form to Form2Stackov.

Comment: Worth noting: `cb` is a Hungarian Notation prefix, short for *count of bytes*. A symbol designating the *count of characters* has a `cch` prefix.

Comment: The RTL has a [`ByteLength()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.ByteLength) function in the `SysUtils` unit, which returns the number of bytes occupied by a `String`'s character payload, eg: `CDS.cbData := ByteLength(S);`

Comment: This is still wrong because the receiver relies on the null terminator. So either use the byte count in the receiver (better), or use `Length()+1` in the sender. And there are many more errors as I mention in my comment to the question.

Comment: Beware of `ByteLength`. Only useful for a native UTF-16 string. For a byte string you'll find the string converted to UTF-16, and then the byte length of that reported. As designed, but scope for confusion.

Comment: @David, I don't understand the solution that u say it's better, and confusion part is it has an "or". `Length(S)` when S become an AnsiString worked.

Comment: `ByteLength` is fine here. It just can catch you out if you pass it a byte string. But that would not be the case here. The real issue is the null terminator. This answer fails to account for that. But in any case, I would not rely on the null terminator. I'd use the code here and change the receiver to use `SetString` and a length of `cbData div 2`.