# Prevent a TWinControl instance to lose focus

Tags: delphi

How can I prevent a TWinControl instance (for example TEdit) to lose focus when user presses TAB or clicking somewhere else?
I want to do some checking about the input before user can leave the control.

update: sorry, I forgot to mention I'm writing a new component (inherited from TCustomEdit) and I want to prevent the focus loss in the component's code.

Comment: This is the wrong way: check when the user **is leaving** the control. But it's your choice to keep your overall aim hidden, hence you must expect suggestions like these.

Comment: Bad things happen when the OS is in the middle of a focus change and validation fails and the control decides to throw an exception or move focus somewhere else. You can easily get the system into a bad UI state. This is a really bad design choice.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I could understand your standpoint, and also agree somehow, but in this case thats what our customer want, I have no impact on this decision. Normaly I prefer checking the inputs before the usage, for example when clicks the post/save/OK/whatever button.

Comment: This is definitely a bad idea, even if it is a customer's wish. Maybe you could convince him that checking the input and displaying a (non modal) error is better than "trapping" the user in a control?

Comment: thanks, but I have no influence on our customer's decision, I'm working for a big company, I never ever gonna meet/talk to the customers and my boss not too interested about my concerns.

Answer (score 1):

For validating the input when leaving a control you can use the [`OnExit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.OnExit) event.

Comment: thanks, but can you explain a bit further please? the problem is not the validation point, but preventing the control to loose the focus.

Comment: @tcxbalage In that event you can set the focus to your control again, so you don't have to care how the focus is about to change (keys `Tab`, `F10`, `Alt` etc... or mouse click/scroll/move or screen swipe...).

Comment: thanks. thats what I'm doing right now, call SetFocus in the CMExit event in the component, but in this way the the OnEnter event triggered too, so I just thought there is a more elegant way to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: @tcxbalage the `OnExit` event handler will be called only if your `CMExit` handler (FYI, you should be `override`'ing the virtual `DoExit()` method instead) calls the base `inherited` handler.  So do your validation, and skip calling the base handler if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can´t comment yet, this seems to me as if a Windowsmessage Handler is required.

something like procedure WNDMessageHandler(var Message: TMessage);

i currently don´t recall how its correctly done. But you can define that a specific procedure handles a Windows Message. (Found [Delphi: WM_COPYDATA work once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389095/delphi-wm-copydata-work-once))
So after that you have to identify all Messages that lead to "leaving" your Form and i guess from there you can solve the clients requirement.

For identification of the messages i used the Spy++ Tool from the microsoft dev Kit, but there is also at least one other. [Spy++ current Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019)

Hint there is a windows function to check which thread has currently the user input. And there is the function BringToFront.